# NIST approved Random Number Generator(Hash_DRBG) in JAVA

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle

I want to generate a SALT value using NIST-approved algorithm(Hash_DRBG). I implemented the below code using SecureRandom in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom ranGen = new SecureRandom();
    BasicEntropySourceProvider bcEntropySourceProvider= new BasicEntropySourceProvider(ranGen, true);
    new SHA256Digest();
    HashSP800DRBG hs=new HashSP800DRBG(new SHA256Digest(), 256, bcEntropySourceProvider.get(256), null, null);
     byte[] output = new byte[8];
     hs.generate(output, null, true);
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, output).toString());
}
```

I am using HashSP800DRBG implementation of Hash_DRGB by BC. 
Editing this question and adding the implementation as it might be useful.
Please let me know what are the approved lengths for the SALT value by NIST.

Comment: Found an implementing class in BC "org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng.drbg.HashSP800DRBG". Has anyone tried using this? Or any code sample for the use of this class

Comment: Those questions are off-topic too.

Comment: Figured out the implementation using the BC. Adding the same as it might help others !!!